# Is there a way to automatically generate text versions of HTML emails for Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to generate basic text emails from my HAML/HTML templates that include the links (strip_tags won't work) and possibly with some simple text transformations of the content for bold, lists, etc.

I remember having a gem doing this long ago, but I can't find one compatible with Rails 3.0.

This is to avoid having to create 2x the emails and view files and having to do some abstraction of the content. I just want the content there, I don't care so much how it looks as non-HTML email clients are pretty rare these days.

Comment: Give your reasoning I dont think you even need the `*.text.erb` templates. Most of the email clients display the text portion of HTML.

Comment: I agree- haven't seen email clients that render the text part in ages. However I have read that having the text portion helps with the inbox delivery and staying out of the spam folder, so this sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The `premailer-rails3` gem offers this https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Markerb](https://github.com/plataformatec/markerb)

It lets you write your mailer template in Markdown, and it auto-makes html and text versions of your email for sending as multipart mime.

Comment: Thanks - that's useful but my emails are much "prettier" than markdown would allow. Lots of CSS etc

Comment: A warning for the next person, it looks like MarkerB has been [archived on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/markerb) and throws depreciation warnings on Rails 6. This is easy to fix, but I don't have bandwidth to maintain a fork of this project at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this functionality once or you do not want to include and external dependency, you can also do this:

```rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  using HtmlConverter

  def some_email
    mail(to: 'personexample.net', subject: "Nice email") do |format|
      format.html
      format.text { render plain: render_to_string('some_email.html').html_to_plain }
  end
end
```

We let the html render to a string which we then strip of the tags. Then we send this as plain text version of the mail.

The code for the String conversion is:

```rb
# I added a refinement to extend the String class
module HtmlConverter
  refine String do
    def html_to_plain
      preprocessed = self.gsub("<hr>", "\n--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---\n")
      ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(preprocessed)
        .split("\n").map(&:strip).join("\n") # fix indentation
        .gsub("\n\n\n", "\n") # remove extensive new lines
        .strip
    end
  end
end
```